# select query with 2 columns having the same name in node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm using Node.js lately with express framework and I am executing a join tables  query where they have 1 column with the same name but the output object puts only 1 of the columns as if it overwrites the other one.

```
mysqlConnection.query("select * from instructor i,course c where c.idi=i.idi",(err,rows,field)=>{
                if(!err){
                    console.log(rows[0])
        }else{
            console.log(err)
        }
    })
```

and the output is the 1st row but with all the attributes except for the instructor description

Answer (score 1):

You need to rename one of the columns using "as", so your query (for example) will be:

```
select *, c.name as course_name 
from instructor i,course c where c.idi=i.idi
```

where the column "name" is the column present in both tables

Comment: Thank you for the help what I actually tried was this:
select  c.name as course_name,*
from instructor i,course c where c.idi=i.idi

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `select *`. You should enumerate the the columns that you expect in the `select` clause, using proper aliases to avoid ambiguity when the same column name exists across tables.

Also, *always* use modern join syntax (with the `on` keyword):

```
select i.idi as instructor_id, ... -- other columns to return
from instructor i 
inner join course c on c.idi = i.idi
```

Also, if you just need one row, you can sort and limit directly in the database; this will be more efficient that fetching the whole dataset in your application and disregard anything but the first record. Note that *consistently* selecting the top record requires a column for sort:

```
select i.idi as instructor_id, ... -- other columns to return
from instructor i 
inner join course c on c.idi = i.idi
order by i.idi -- or another column
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should rename the attributes that you want to select in your SQL query, something like this:

```
select i.description as i_description, c.description as c_description
from instructor i, course c,
where i.idi = c.idi
```

And then the `row[0]` object should have both description in the `i_description` and `c_description` attributes respectively.